# WebGL render blank screen in MacOS sandbox

Tags: macos, electron, webgl, appstore-sandbox

I have an app that runs WebGL to render video for Mac App (Electron). It works fine when running on local build. However it renders blank screen on MacOS app store bulid in Sandbox mode. Checked the frames passed to shader and it looks ok. What could be wrong in this case? Any permission do we need for Mac App store build?

info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.application-identifier</key>
    <string>xxxxx.desktop.xxxxx</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
    <string>xxxxx</string>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <string>xxxxx.desktop.xxxxx</string>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.server</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.camera</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.microphone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.audio-input</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.usb</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.bluetooth</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-write</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Could you share your Entitlements.plist?

Comment: updated @mahaltertin